# AlpineJS x-on:keypress, how to get which key

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

is there anywhere info about @keypress / x-on:keypress of AlpineJS?

```
<body class="antialiased bg-black" x-data @keypress="console.log()">
```

What should I put into log() to get data which key has been pressed? I cant find anything about that in documentation. I want to send pressed key to livewire controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpine will pass a `$event` variable

If you do

`<body class="antialiased bg-black" x-data @keypress="console.log($event)">`

Then you'll see one of the props on the $event is the key pressed

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what specific key you wan't to detect but you can do something like this :

```
<button type="text" @keyup.enter="alert('Submitted!')">Awesome button !</button>
```

[Link to the documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#keyboard-events)

Comment: Yeah, but i want to detect wich key has been pressed by alpine, however i connect vanilla js to livewire due to cannot find way by alpinejs.

Comment: I've found this way : 
<div @keydown.window="alert('ok')"></div>
It detecs the window keydown event